# segfault при использовании статической библиотеки

Tags: c, kotlin-native

AS Скорее всего многое из того, что перечислю, вообще не по делу, но я просто не знаю, в какую сторону копать.

Суть проблемы: Когда компилирую С-шный проект с зависимостью от динамической библиотеки, то все работает. Когда с той-же самой, но статической - падает в segmentation fault.

Библиотека из одной функции

```
fun kt_print(string: String) {
    println("Hello, $string!!!")
}
```

Компилирую так

```
kotlinc ./hellokt.kt -o hellokt -produce static   //libhellokt.a
kotlinc ./hellokt.kt -o hellokt -produce dynamic  //libhellokt.so
```

Подключаю ее в С-шный проект расширения PHP

config.m4

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(hello, whether to enable hello support,[ --enable-hello   Enable hello support])

if test "$PHP_HELLO" != "no"; then
    PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/root/simpleExtension)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(hellokt, /root/simpleExtension, HELLO_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_SUBST(HELLO_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(hello, hello.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

Со статической библиотекой:
1) Если где-то в коде использую kt_print - падает.
2) Если не использую вызов kt_print, то не падает.
2) Падает не на вызове функции, а при zend_register_functions (т.е. как минимум php_load_extension и zend_register_module_ex отрабатывают)

```
(gdb) run -dextension=./modules/hello.so -r "echo hello('JoE');"
Starting program: /opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin/php -dextension=./modules/hello.so -r "echo hello('JoE');"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555557b0682 in zend_register_functions ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555557b0682 in zend_register_functions ()
#1  0x00005555557b16b7 in zend_register_module_ex ()
#2  0x00005555556ecc36 in php_load_extension ()
#3  0x000055555579dace in zend_llist_apply ()
#4  0x000055555574f59a in php_ini_register_extensions ()
#5  0x0000555555747da9 in php_module_startup ()
#6  0x000055555584796d in php_cli_startup ()
#7  0x0000555555624838 in main ()
```

Кусок вывода `make`, с подключением либы

```
/bin/sh /root/simpleExtension/libtool --mode=link cc \
  -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/simpleExtension/include \
  -I/root/simpleExtension/main \
  -I/root/simpleExtension \
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php \
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php/main 
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php/TSRM \
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php/Zend \
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php/ext \
  -I/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib \
  -I/root/simpleExtension  \
  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o hello.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version 
  -prefer-pic -module -rpath /root/simpleExtension/modules  hello.lo \
  -Wl,-rpath,/root/simpleExtension -L/root/simpleExtension -lhellokt

libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/hello.o   \
  -L/root/simpleExtension -lhellokt  -O2 \
  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/root/simpleExtension -Wl,-soname -Wl,hello.so -o .libs/hello.so
```

В чем может быть проблема? Может дополнительная диагностика нужна?

Comment: Huh?! Вы нигде даже не пытаетесь в примерах соединить её статически.

Comment: @0andriy я буду очень благодарен, если вы подскажете как "соединить ее статически". Интернеты говорят, что `-Lpath -llib` подходят как для static так и для shared

Comment: Для начала поменяйте shared на static.

Comment: @0andriy вы бы вопрос прочитали для начала. Компиляция библиотеки описана во втором сверху блоке кода. Последний блок кода - это финальная компиляция проекта с подключением вышескомпилированной либы

Comment: Я вам и говорю про последний блок сборки.

Comment: @0andriy последний блок сборки ДОЛЖЕН собирать разделяемую библиотеку. Проблема в библиотеке, которая включается в нее.

Comment: Запутанно как, но да ладно. Пробовали просто _*.a_ файл подключать как ещё один объектный файл при линковке?

Comment: @0andriy да. Именно в том и проблема, что когда я на стадии линковки подключаю .so, то все ок, а когда .a - segfault.

Comment: А объектные файлы котлин совместимы с С?

Comment: @VTT да, на то он и Native собственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел как починить, но первопричина до сих пор не понятна.

Проблема в коде на С (напомню, что это расширение PHP). В момент определения массива функций, необходимо добавить одну строку

```
static zend_function_entry hello_functions[] = {
        PHP_FE(hello, NULL)
        {NULL,NULL,NULL}       // Вот эту, в самом конце определения массива
};
```

Почему без этой строки все прекрасно компилировалось и работало при использовании разделяемой библиотеки и падало при использовании статической - не понятно.

**Объясняющий комментарий от @VTT**

> Это потому что массивы zend_function_entry должны заканчиваться
>   нулевым элементом, иначе рантайм php (у которого есть только
>   указатель) не остановится вовремя и начнет читать за пределами
>   массива. Видимо при использовании динамической библиотеки в блоке
>   памяти для статических переменных дальше шли нули, а при использовании
>   статической библиотеки в блок памяти для статических переменных
>   попадало что-то еще и последующие zend_function_entry с мусором
>   начинали использоваться php.

Comment: Это потому что массивы `zend_function_entry` должны заканчиваться нулевым элементом, иначе рантайм php (у которого есть только указатель) не остановится вовремя и начнет читать за пределами массива. Видимо при использовании динамической библиотеки в блоке памяти для статических переменных дальше шли нули, а при использовании статической библиотеки в блок памяти для статических переменных попадало что-то еще и последующие `zend_function_entry` с мусором начинали использоваться php.